# PasswordBox in CellTemplate goes empty after double click

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, passwordbox

I use WPF and MVVM for a project and have the following problem: When I double click on my Password DataGrid cell and then focus on another cell, the PasswordBox in the CellTemplate goes empty. The TextBox on the other hand keeps its value. (This doesn't happen when I use tab.)

Here is the XAML code of my cell:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <PasswordBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Focusable="False" IsEnabled="False"
                                     basics:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True"  
                                     basics:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                  Text="{Binding Path=Password, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Because I want to use bindings for my PasswordBox I used the PasswordHelper as defined here: http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html

I'm pretty new to WPF and couldn't find anything helpful online.

**Edit**

I changed the PasswordBox to a TextBox and used a converter to change the String to look like a password. Now it works fine and looks like I want it to look! (And it's easier too. The PasswordBox combined with the Helper I used seems to bug a bit.)

Comment: Have you tried adding _UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged_ to the BoundPassword Binding?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What happens when you throw out _Focusable="False" IsEnabled="False"_?

Comment: Why `Focusable="False"` and `IsEnabled="False"` ? remove it

Comment: Then it will focus the PasswordBox and not the TextBox when I click on it and I won't be able to see the password in a readable sting at all!

Comment: And even if I let it out, the problem stays the same. As soon as I click on the TextBox (it's possible if I click between the PasswordBox border and the cell border) the PasswordBox gets empty. I suppose that there is something wrong with the code I use for the PasswordHelper but I can't find what exactly.